# Having trouble making navigation transparent with scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `View` - `ScrollView` - `View` and am having trouble making the navigation completely transparent. I have set 0,0,0,0 constraints for all 3 parts in the hierarchy.

In my `ViewController` I have the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

However, this shortens the white navigation but does not make it transparent to the top, like this:[image]

I uploaded my test project here - https://github.com/cluelessoodles/testScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You pinned your view top the safe area, not the view. Make sure you select the top level view when creating your top constraint, not the safe area:

[image]

This applies to the bottom constraint as well if you want it to stretch to the very bottom of the iPhone X screen.

Comment: Hey, I check my constraints, and they are pinned to the parentView not the safeArea. Here's a photo - https://imgur.com/a/fnZpLvu. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

When setting the constraints make sure you did not set them on the Save Area but on the Parent View, this should do the trick if I understood your question correctly

Comment: Hey, I do have my constraints set to the ParentView not the Safe Area. here's a photo: https://imgur.com/a/fnZpLvu. I still have not been able to solve this. All of my constraints set 0,0,0,0 on all 3 views. I have also added a test projec to my original post, if you can take a look and maybe spot what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want the Status bar to also be "transparent". For that make sure your constraints are set to TOP = 0 relative to the main view (for the scroll view and the view you added inside the scroll). Also, by doing this, you will have scrollable content behind the status bar and I am not sure if that's the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. I just added a screenshot of my constraints. I believe I have them at 0 but they dont show up so. Should the Y be a negative number?

Comment: My constraints are set to the top as far as I can tell. Here's a photo my constraints - https://imgur.com/a/fnZpLvu. Could you take a look? I still have not been able to solve this.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I was out of office for a week. So what you want is to "remove" the white space at the top when the VC first loads? If so, that has something to do with the scroll view and you have to go to the View Controller Scene and disable the checkbox near "Adjust Scroll View Insets". Check it out here: https://imgur.com/a/V0XSbUf . Also on the scroll view you have to set de bottom constraint relative to the Safe Area and the "Content Insets" property to "Never".